# Viewing Unparented bugs and tasks in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We have recently upgraded to TFS 2015 from TFS 2013.

We've also moved over a project to TFS 2015 (which has been running since TFS 2010) which is using agile process.

We'd like to make use of the task board to display bugs and tasks, and almost all of them are not linked to a parent yet.

When I go to  'Working with bugs'-> 'Bugs appear on the backlogs and boards with tasks'

I only see user stories appearing on the task board (and any tasks linked to a user story). Please let me know how I can configure unparented  bugs and tasks to appear on the board.

Answer (score 2):

You should install to TFS2015 Update 1 (or better to Update 2) in order to have the unparented bugs displayed in task board.

Comment: I have got TFS update 1 installed. I can also see unparented bugs and tasks in a separate scrum project that I have.

Comment: With the agile project, when I go to the board settings page I don''t see the bugs and tasks tabs either (Only user stories tab appear). Compared to the scrum project which has got user stories, tasks and tabs in settings page once I configured the 'Working with bugs' section.